# Filter a numpy array by function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array in the following form:

```
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6]])
```

I want to filter out the rows that their first value is bigger than 1, but I couldn't find a numpy function to do so.

I know that I can use `filter`:

```
np.array(list(filter((lambda x: x[0] <= 1), my_arr)))
```

This approach is not efficient, since I need to convert the result into list and only than into numpy array. Is there a better way?

Comment: You generally should prefer list comprehensions to map/filter, btw.

Answer (score 1):

There is not `numpy` interface to do this efficiently with a function. However, in this *particular* case, you just want something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[0, 4],
...        [1, 5],
...        [2, 6]])
>>> arr[arr[:,0] <= 1]
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6]])

newarr=[]

for fetch in arr:
    if(fetch[0]>1):
        newarr.append(fetch)
        
print(newarr)
```